# How to access react navigation params outside react-native-drawer component

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Initial Screen Splash than navigate to Home Screen & parameter set. I want to get parameter inside sidebar Component.

```
const navigateActionHome = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'drawerStack',
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ 
        routeName: 'HomeScreen' , 
        params : { username : 'Testing' }
    })
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateActionHome)

// drawer stack
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: DashboardScreen },
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen }
},{
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "red"
    },
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
});
```

I'm able to get "username" parameter in HomeScreen Component, but can't get "username" parameter inside Sidebar Component.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you start this screen here:

```
contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
```

You are passing the "props" of the screen but not the params. Those are not the same. You could confirm by debugging and stopping anywhere on your screen to see if your screen have that prop.

Just take whatever way you are getting that username param in your screen and you can add it like this:

```
contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} username={myUsername} />
```

Comment: How I can push data to "myUsername" from API